# Поясните следующую конструкцию в классе Thread

Tags: java

Что это за конструкция: `synchronized` (что-то в круглых скобках) {блок в фигурных скобках} ?

```
synchronized (blockerLock) {
            Interruptible b = blocker;
            if (b != null) {
                interrupt0();           // Just to set the interrupt flag
                b.interrupt(this);
                return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Дайте нормальный заголовок вопросу

Comment: [Intrinsic Locks and Synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)

Comment: tym32167, огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: парни, а есть у кого в заначке(закладках) статейка/статеища, которая в свое время просто озарила вас на тему потоков? типа: «так вот как оно на самом деле работает!» пс: понятно, что в моем распоряжении и доки оракла и я уже кое-что нагуглил на хабре, но тем не менее я задаю этот вопрос)) спс.